# is there a "GUI overflow?" -- a discussion group for user interfaces that includes ability to experience the code being discussed?

Tags: support, area-51, site-proposal

Has anyone combined discussion of code with exhibition of running code?

It would be nice to have a version of stackoverflow that dealt with user-interface issues, and allowed people not to just to read small code snippets but experience medium sized applets.

Is there anything like that already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have used the search on Area 51:

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5728/user-interface

Comment: Indeed if I had only known that were in Area 51 along with the dead aliens and the ark of the covenant -- oh wait -- I see a link at the bottom of the page -- and those look like LIVE ALIENS.... thanks